# unable to upgrade firefox

Tags: upgrade

When I try to upgrade firefox on Ubuntu I get this message in the terminal

```
E: Type '$' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release-bionic.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Type '$' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release-bionic.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96028/discussion-on-question-by-burt-unable-to-upgrade-firefox).

Answer (score 1):

**From the comments...**

`cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release-bionic.list`

**Output is...**

```
 $ sudo apt update $ sudo apt install brave-browser brave-keyring
```

**So do this...**

Delete the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release-bionic.list` file, as its contents are completely invalid.

`sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release-bionic.list`

Comment: @burt please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the grey checkmark icon just to the left of my answer. Thanks!